# Paypal Checkout button with React not letting signed in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, paypal

I am having issues integrating the Paypal with my react app using sandbox. When I click on the Button, a pop-up of PayPal opens and when I put in my credentials to log in, I get the following error:

[image: Paypal popup]
[image: Paypal error]

I am able to see the sign in form, but it just won't let me sign in and instead I come to see that message.

**App.js**

```
import PaypalButton from './PaypalButton';

const CLIENT = {
  sandbox: 'xxxxx',
  production: 'xxxxx',
};

const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'production' : 'sandbox';

render() {     
  const onSuccess = (payment) =>
    console.log('Successful payment!', payment);

  const onError = (error) =>
    console.log('Erroneous payment OR failed to load script!', error);

  const onCancel = (data) =>
    console.log('Cancelled payment!', data);

  return(
    <div>
        <PaypalButton
          client={CLIENT}
          env={ENV}
          commit={true}
          currency={'USD'}
          total={500.00}
          onSuccess={onSuccess}
          onError={onError}
          onCancel={onCancel}
        />
    </div>
  )
}
```

**PaypalButton**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import scriptLoader from 'react-async-script-loader';

class PaypalButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      showButton: false,
    };

    window.React = React;
    window.ReactDOM = ReactDOM;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const {
      isScriptLoaded,
      isScriptLoadSucceed
    } = this.props;

    if (isScriptLoaded && isScriptLoadSucceed) {
      this.setState({ showButton: true });
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const {
      isScriptLoaded,
      isScriptLoadSucceed,
    } = nextProps;

    const isLoadedButWasntLoadedBefore =
      !this.state.showButton &&
      !this.props.isScriptLoaded &&
      isScriptLoaded;

    if (isLoadedButWasntLoadedBefore) {
      if (isScriptLoadSucceed) {
        this.setState({ showButton: true });
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {
      total,
      currency,
      env,
      commit,
      client,
      onSuccess,
      onError,
      onCancel,
    } = this.props;

    const {
      showButton,
    } = this.state;

    const payment = () =>
      paypal.rest.payment.create(env, client, {
        transactions: [
          {
            amount: {
              total,
              currency,
            }
          },
        ],
      });

    const onAuthorize = (data, actions) =>
      actions.payment.execute()
        .then(() => {
          const payment = {
            paid: true,
            cancelled: false,
            payerID: data.payerID,
            paymentID: data.paymentID,
            paymentToken: data.paymentToken,
            returnUrl: data.returnUrl,
          };

          onSuccess(payment);
        });

    return (
      <div>
        {showButton && <paypal.Button.react
          env={env}
          client={client}
          commit={commit}
          payment={payment}
          onAuthorize={onAuthorize}
          onCancel={onCancel}
          onError={onError}
        />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default scriptLoader('https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js')(PaypalButton);
```

Can someone please help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue last week. After working for a while, the sandbox started giving me that error. I reverted all my commits to ensure it wasn't an issue with my code. After a day or two, it started to work again.

Seems it was an issue with PayPal's sandbox environment. ([Apparently it happens to the best of us](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=ie7&q=Things+don%27t+appear+to+be+working+at+the+moment.+Please+try+again+later.+sandbox&rls=com.microsoft:en-US:%7Breferrer:source?%7D&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&rlz=1I7TSNF)).

If you had been sending incorrect data, you would have seen a `console.log` of the error.

Comment: You're absolutely right, Avremel. It was an issue from PayPal. It started working again just fine without changing anything in the code.